# ^] doesn't work if cursor is on a function name prefixed with its package in Perl

Tags: ctags

**Problem:** `^]` doesn't work if cursor is on a function name prefixed with its package.

---

I am using `ctags` and by reading the `tags` file generated I ensured that the sub is indexed in the tags file, like:

`a_func_like_this lib/Package/Module.pm    /^  sub a_func_like_this {$/;    s"`

So it works if my cursor is on `a_func_like_this`.

However if the full name is specified (along with its module) like `Package::Module::a_func_like_this`, `^]` would search for the full name which is not indexed by `ctags`.

It's like the default behaviour of `^]` is `yiw :tag <C-r>"<CR>`.  Which implies that `Package::Module::a_func_like_this` is being searched and thus returns no result.

As a workaround I want it to just get the part after `::` if that presents in the Inner Word.

That said, even with such work around, I may have to manually select the correct version of `a_func_like_this` even though the exact file I am looking for is clearly `Package::Module` (the part discarded). I guess `vi` should have something smarter for tag jumping.

How should I approach this?

Comment: I am sorry for the problem being unclear. The mapping is working - it's like its default behavior is `yaw :tag <C-r>"<CR>`, which doesn't work for full function names because the `Package::` part is captured by `yaw`. A workaround is to use `yiw` however I may have to manually find the correct version of the function though the package is explicitly seen.  Any ideas to make the tag jumping smarter?

Comment: Maybe the proper solution involves a config of ctags instead of a vim issue?

Comment: I have just read the ctags manual. Seems that the `--fields` option may be useful. I'll instead try YouCompleteMe to see if that's handled better there...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks I have figured it out.

Instead of a plain `ctags -R`, run `ctags -R --extra=+q` which also adds the prefix-ed version of the methods into the tags file.